# Split string in two string?

Tags: php, string

I have one string that goes like this

```
$value="1000,00+1000x522";
```

I need to get two string from `$value`

```
$string1="1000,00";
$string2="1000x522";
```

But this string $value can have different value long, but always **+** will be delimiter from first and second new strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`list()`](https://www.php.net/list) and [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$value="1000,00+1000x522";
list($string1, $string2) = explode('+', $value);
```